# How to handle Timezones between Angular and Spring boot

Tags: javascript, angular, spring-boot

I have an application which i have deployed in a server at Paris. The users are from India. Because of this, the date is taken as one day before. Whatever date i am getting from backend is getting displayed as one day before. Whatever date i try to send to backend, the backend is taking one day before. Can anyone suggest how to tackle this problem?

Comment: Never send timestamp between client and server. Always use string values like `20-12-2020` and when persisting it into the database, use server time

Comment: there are some cases where we require date object as well. In that case, how can we handle with Date objects?

Comment: You can create a date object from a string anywhere. But passing timestamp between two platforms with different timezones, you'll always run into problems.

Comment: yes, therefore Java has ZonedDateTime, LocalDateTime and so on. Do you use talking about the angular side or the backend side (Spring or DB)? 

and do you talking about dates (days) or about date-times? There is often a problem, when handling dates in the fronent, but datetimes in the backend.

Comment: @Indivon actually i have problems in both sides. I am using normal java.util.date only. In front end, whenever i create a date object, it is taking previous date when timezones are different

Comment: and whats about your input in angular? Dates only or dates with time?

Comment: At angular side, its date alone. The date is displayed and it can be inputted as well. In both cases, i am facing issue if timezones are different.